# Smooth chart update from multithreaded data source

Tags: c#, wpf, graph, telerik, system.reactive

We have several graphs that show filtered data from surface EMG sensors. This data is received over TCP and propagated using an event. The datapackets are of type DataPackets and are as such filtered out. I'm using a buffer to let packets pass through at 30FPS. I'm listening to this event using Reactive Extensions as follows:

```cs
Observable.FromEvent<Packet>(h => this.DataService.PacketReceived += h, h=> this.DataService.PacketReceived -= h)
          .OfType<DataPacket>()
          .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0 / 30))
          .ObserveOnDispatcher()
          .Subscribe(
              packet => this.ReceiveDataPackets(packet.ToList()),
              err => this.Log.Error("Error subscribing to data packets", err),
              () => this.Log.Info("Finished listening to data packets"));
```

To display the EMG data we use the Telerik ChartView. The problem I'm having is that data update is not smooth, the graph is choppy.

There are probably several reasons for this:

1. Telerik chart is not fast enough for 1000 data points per second
2. DispatcherTimer does not fire at a constant rate
3. data is not received at a constant rate

Point 1 is solved by sampling the input data so that only 1000 points are visible in the graph.

Point 2 cannot be solved unfortunately. I tried raising the priority to Render but this does not help at all. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5eea6700-1c79-4da6-9b68-efa480ed3a36/simplify-wpf-dispatcher-calls?forum=rx

Point 3 is related to point 2. I try to solve both with a timed queue using `System.Debug.Stopwatch`. DataPackets contain a timestamp and this is used to let them through at a constant rate on the Dispatcher thread. I suspect that this will not help much since the DispatcherRate is not linked to refresh rate of the renderthread.

What can I do to reduce choppiness? I tried LightningChart Ultimate which is supposed to be much much faster. It does indeed have much better performance and there is no need to do any sampling, it can render each and every datapoint. The samples provided with LightningChart run butter smooth, but they read their data in the main thread. When I implement their chart in our multi-threaded program it still suffers from a combination of point 2 and 3 (and the fact that it is much more expensive than the Telerik chartview.)

[Update]

Classic mistake. My datasource was using a DispatcherTimer to gather data. Changing this to an Observable.Interval massively increased performance.

Comment: I can see a solution in one of two ways. Either create a buffer for data points and swap it out every tick (this may cause the chart to lag if there is a lot of data) or have a fixed number of points and interpolate the data points every tick to converge to the new values (this will recycle objects and increase performance at the expense of data accuracy).

Comment: The first way is exactly what I do, but since the DispatcherTimer tick is not in sync with the render updates there is significant visual jitter.

Comment: For faster graphs, you might want to look at https://oxyplot.codeplex.com/ - I've found it to be faster than D3 (and nicer appearance). It's actively maintained as well.

Comment: For LightningChart use, the data input is very small part of the UI time need. Use BeginUpdate...EndUpdate around the code you are using, to prevent it from rendering several times. LightningChart has also Sweeping mode for EMG, EKG and EEG plotting, it means it keeps the old page of data in the background then renders a new page on top of it. It gives better visual appearance and gets rids of choppiness produced by memory garbage collecting. I used to work in biomed industry creating these kind of applications before writing LightningChart v.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had similar troubles with chart control [a while ago](http://leecampbell.blogspot.co.uk/2010/01/my-wpf-charting-comparisons.html). I too found that most charting controls just could not handle 1000+ datapoints. I also found that trying to get it re-render more than 5-15 times per second was pretty tough on the dispatcher.

Things I would suggest to you are:

1. Aim for a much lower frame rate. You are hoping to get updates to your chart every 33ms?
2. Look to reduce your data set to 1000 points. Again play with the numbers to see what works for your target spec PC and your controls/datatemplating. [This old post](http://leecampbell.blogspot.co.uk/2010/02/squeezing-out-performance-from-charting.html) may help you. It provides a way to pick the X most useful points to render from a collection
3. Dial back any fancy animations or extra UI that is rendered per point on the chart. if you are adding more items that each have tool tips, brushes, animations and excess layout panels, you will pay the cost. Also note that you will not only pay the cost as they are created, but also later when the GC tries to clear out these thousands of UI objects.
4. Do less work on the dispatcher. I know it is not much, but you could move that `ToList()` and do it on the other thread. Also, dont send empty lists to be processed (if applicable to your events)
5. Consider using the [D3/DDD charts](http://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com/). While they were not great when I reviewed them, colleagues have had success with them since then.

   ```
   Observable.FromEvent<Packet>(h => this.DataService.PacketReceived += h, h=> this.DataService.PacketReceived -= h)
     .OfType<DataPacket>()
     .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0 / 8))  //Reduce the FPS
     .Select(packet=>packet.ToList())        //Reduce work done on dispatcher
     .Where(packet=>packet.Count>0)          //Dont send empty sets to dispatcher
     .ObserveOnDispatcher()
     .Subscribe(
         packet => this.ReceiveDataPackets(packet),
         err => this.Log.Error("Error subscribing to data packets", err),
         () => this.Log.Info("Finished listening to data packets"));
   ```

I am not sure if it helps, but here is [another link](http://leecampbell.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/rx-code-from-perth-presentation.html) to some code from a presentation. Part of the presentation was about how to stream data via Rx to a WPF Chart. You could potentially rip the whole thing.

Comment: Actually at my old job, one of the biggest perf tweeks you can do is to move the windowing onto another thread. So you only do UI updates on the data points that are visible on the screen. The work to this was insane, however you have very little choice. Switch all text rendering to using `Glyph`s.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but it might help somebody here.

If you want to display data from sensors in a WPF Chart it will be pretty slow if you use the standard open source chart components, or most commercial vendors such as Telerik.

I would like to suggest my own component: [SciChart](https://www.scichart.com/wpf-chart-features), which is displaying millions of points with millisecond updates in WPF.

SciChart is a commercial component, and *I would like to disclose that yes I am the owner*, however, no free or open source alternatives can come close to it in terms of usability or performance.

Please take a look at the page [Why SciChart - the Best WPF Chart](https://www.scichart.com/why-scichart-the-best-wpf-chart/) as this has some specific performance demos / videos that you can view. It supports multi-threaded updating of data and can cope with 1,000 points / second.

Comment: I second the description given in this post. Forget most WPF libraries if you need to chart 1000+ data points. The only game in town is Scichart or Arction's Lightningchart. I found many of Arction's claims dubious and unsubstantiated, their styling looks horrible and is not MVVM friendly at all, which leaves me for over 6 years using Scichart as my go-to library for WPF. Keep the good work up, Andy